# Image created with blob only contains numbers and commas

Tags: javascript, php, tizen

I have a file on my device that is stored in a folder like:

```
/opt/share/folder/image.jpg
```

I'd like to upload this file on my server using some ajax request just as I'd do with a standard HTML form.

After few searches, I've come to create a Blob file and upload it on the server; this works. But the problem is that my jpeg at the arrival is *corrupted* and contains a suit of numbers and commas (technically, Bytes of the source file):

```
255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,8,6,6,7,6,5,8,7,7
```

The Filesystem API of Tizen allows me to open this file and read its bytes - which is what I do. So I use the following code to read bytes, create a blob and upload it on my server:

```
var raw = fs.readBytes(1024);                    
var blob = new Blob([raw], {type:"image/jpeg"});
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('screenCapture', blob);

$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: myurl,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   data: formData,
   success: function(data){
             ...

   },
   error: function(jqxhr, status, msg){
          console.log("ERROR! " + msg);
          }
});
```

Comment: I believe your Ajax request is sending the Data as JSON and not as a binary represantation. You will need to convert the json back to a binary Format on your Server. You also could consider converting the Image to a Base64-format before sending it over the wire. This way you can assure that the data will not be corrupted due to some characterset conversions etc.

Comment: @treeno the datas are send as a form data, which means that the created file arrive correctly on server side.
But trying to append this blob as img with blueimp loadImage library reveals that the blob isn't correct at source. It seems that the readBytes doesn't creates a correct bytes array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong with my code.

In fact, readBytes return an array of number corresponding to bytes, but the array isn't formatted as a byte array.

Creating a new Uint8Array from this array did the trick:

```
var raw = fs.readBytes(1024);
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(raw);
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type:"image/jpeg"});
```