# File length is undefined

Tags: javascript, file, filereader, tizen

Using the Filesystem API of Tizen SDK, I'm getting a javascript File object that prints the following datas on console.log:

```
File
created: Thu Dec 14 2017 09:59:51 GMT+0100 (CET)
fullPath: "/opt/share/folder/image.jpg"
get fileSize: function fileSizeGetter() {var _realPath=commonFS_.toRealPath(this.fullPath);var _result=native_.callSync('File_statSync',{location:_realPath});var _aStatObj=native_.getResultObject(_result);return _aStatObj.isFile?_aStatObj.size:undefined;}
isDirectory: false
isFile: true
length: undefined
mode: "rw"
modified: Thu Dec 14 2017 09:59:51 GMT+0100 (CET)
name: "image.jpg"
parent: File
path: "/opt/share/folder/"
readOnly: false
set fileSize: function () {}
__proto__: File
```

Problem is that the length of the File is *undefined*. This cause my Filereader readyState to stay at 0 (EMPTY) state (or maybe the problem is somewhere else).

Why is my code returning undefined for length parameter?

My code:

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve('/opt/share/folder/image.jpg', function(file) {
    console.log(file);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    console.log(reader);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = fileLoad;
    reader.onerror = function(evt){
        console.log(evt.target.error.name);
    }
});
```

Console value for reader:

```
FileReader
constructor: FileReaderConstructor
error: null
onabort: null
onerror: function (evt) {
onload: function fileLoad(evt) {
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
readyState: 0
result: null
__proto__: FileReaderPrototype
```

Precision:

Using the file url to insert image in a canvas is working and the file is existing on device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html#File::length), `length` is for `File` instances representing directories (it tells you how many files and directories the directory contains). For a `File` actually representing a file, you'd use [`fileSize`](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html#File::fileSize).

I don't see a `FileReader` anywhere in the [Tizen file system documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html#File::fileSize). Instead, [examples reading and writing files](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/data-storage-and-management/file-system#file_dir) use a `FileStream` via `openStream`.

Comment: Effectively, it seems that File object created by Tizen isn't a standard File object as we'd have with HTML5.
I wanted to try this approach using File and FileReader as the FileStream method was returning me corrupted file on server side as explained on my other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793606/image-created-with-blob-only-contains-numbers-and-commas

Also, thanks for your answer, I'll change my approach on filestream.

Comment: @BananasSplitter: Yes, looks like it's their own thing, presumably because the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) doesn't let you do the things they let you do, and what used to be called the ["Filesystem API"](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) has come to a halt (other than being renamed "File API: Directories and System").

Comment: It has to be their own thing, because the Filesystem API is an interface between your JavaScript based web application and the API of whatever SAMSUNG device you are using. In my case it's usually displays, so when I call Filesystem API I am using JavaScript, while Filesystem API itself is a rapper for C++ code that is used to access display functions.